# How do I take appropriate action after i detect an object in my camera?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to run a normal software using object detection, i can detect an object or color with openCV but after that i can not take any action. like i want to push a button whenever camera detect any color or object.

with this code i can detect any yellow color object but i can't take any action after that.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #yellow color

    low_yellow = np.array([20,60,200])
    high_yellow = np.array([60,255,255])
    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_yellow, high_yellow)
    yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=yellow_mask)

    cv2.imshow("OUR FRAME", frame)
    cv2.imshow("YELLOW FRAME" , yellow)

    key =cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key ==27:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are not really detecting objects yet, you are taking whatever image the camera is seeing and applying a yellow filter to it. But if there were no yellow object the screen would still display.

To get to what you are looking for I suggest looking into "blob detection" This is probably the simplest form of object detection. Once you can detect "blobs" I recommend setting a threshold for size and deciding if an object if worth reacting to based on that.